# Deploying an add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, office-2010, office-addins

I have created a VSTO add-in for Outlook using VS2013 for Outlook 2010.  I need to deploy this add-in to 100 computers/users.

What's the quickest and most painless method of deploying this add-in to 100 computers/users?

Comment: What about an installer?

Comment: With an installer, will I be able to somehow run that installer on 100 computers all at the same time, or will I have to go to each computer physically to run the installer?

Comment: Take a look at group policies. Also a scheduled task or a startupprogram could be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a Windows login script that invokes your installer from a network location.